# setLocale method works on the translations in layout, but not for the ones insided yielded components

Tags: laravel, translation, laravel-blade

I came across an issue while trying to implement a translation system in a Laravel project.

In the layout file, layout.php, I set the language before yielding the contents:

```
<?php
    \App::setLocale(session()->get('language'));
?>
```

And it seems to be working for the @lang instructions that follow (placed inside layout.php).

After those, I yield the content of the page like this:

```
@yield('content')
```

But the @lang instructions in the file that extends the layout (and has the 'content' section) do not work.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`App::setLocale()` is not persistent, locale will only work for current request at runtime. You can create a middleware and enforce locale on each request in the middleware's handle function

```
App::setLocale( session('app_locale', 'fallback_language') );
```

Then in In `app\Http\Kernel.php` under web group register Language middleware after the StartSession middleware as below.

```
protected $middleware = [
   ...
   \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware::class,
   ...
];
```

Checkout this post, https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale its Laravel 5 but concept is the same.